# EPiServer CMO thumbnail service: navigation to the webpage was canceled windows service

Tags: windows-services, episerver, episerver-7

I'm trying to get EPiServer Thumbnail Service to work. It is just a windows service that snaps a snapshot of a webpage.

I think it navigates to the relevant page as a service via internet explorer, but internet explorer only gives the error message: `navigation to the webpage was canceled`.

I've tried to mock about with the security settings in IE, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Could you try to disable firewall on the web server and check if it helps?

Comment: It is in my local dev environment. Tried to disable windows firewall, but it didn't work.